# How to prove the following estimate about higher derivatives of $f$ and $f\circ A$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\Lambda\geq \lambda>0$ so that
$$\lambda |x|\leq |Ax|\leq \Lambda |x|,\qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
let $g=f\circ A,$ I want to prove the following result: for each $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ there is a constant $C$ depending only on $n,k,\Lambda,\lambda$ such that
$$\sup_{|\beta|=k}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|D^\beta g(x)|\leq C \sup_{|\beta|=k}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|D^\beta f
(x)| $$
where $\beta$ denotes multiindex of length $k.$

The case for $k=1$ is simple, since the chain rule tells us
$$Dg(x)=Df(Ax)\cdot A\tag{1}$$
($Dg=(D_1g,...,D_ng)$ is the gradient), so
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{LHS}\leq&~\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|Df(Ax)\cdot A|
\leq\Lambda \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|Df(Ax)|
\\=&~\Lambda \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|Df(x)|\leq \Lambda \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\sup_{1\leq i\leq n}\sqrt{n}|D_if(x)|= \sqrt{n}\lambda\mathrm{RHS}
\end{align}
but when $k\geq 2,$ there is no simple rule similar to $(1),$ so I'm stuck here, can someone help me?

Comment: For those who are not familliar with this notation: "where β denotes multiindex of length k." what do you mean by that?

Comment: This seems doable by induction, have you tried ?

Comment: @YarinMasas That means $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n),$ where each $\beta_i$ is a non-negative integer and $\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i=k,$ and I use the notation $D^\beta u$ to stand for the higher derivative $\frac{\partial^ku}{\partial x_1^{\beta_1}\cdots \partial x_n^{\beta_n}}.$

Comment: @Falcon I have tried it, but it seems to be hard to me even going from $k=1$ to $k=2$ using induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s try some simple cases, but use index notation (instead of matrix multiplication) because this will help us spot the pattern.

Treating $x$ as a column vector, for $k=1$, $$ D_i g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n D_k f(Ax) A_{ik}. $$ For $k=2$, $$D_{ij}g(x) = \sum_{k,\ell=1}^n D_{k\ell}f(Ax) A_{ik}A_{j\ell}$$ Continuing in this way, we get that $$D_{i_1,\dots,i_k}g(x) = \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^n D_{j_1,\dots,j_k}f(Ax) A_{j_1 i_1}\dots A_{j_ki_k}.$$

Hence, given a multiindex $\alpha$ of length $k$, we can write $D^\alpha g = D_{i_1,\dots,i_k}g$ with each $i_\ell \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, so \begin{align*}
\vert D^\alpha g(x) \vert &= \vert D_{i_1,\dots i_k}g(x) \vert \\
&\leq  \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^n \vert D_{j_1,\dots,j_k}f(Ax) \vert \cdot \vert A_{j_1 i_1}\vert\dots \vert A_{j_ki_k} \vert \\
&\leq \sup_{\vert \beta\vert = k} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n}\vert D^\beta f(x)\vert \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^n \vert A_{j_1 i_1}\vert\dots \vert A_{j_ki_k} \vert .
\end{align*} Finally, observe that \begin{align*} \vert  A_{ij}  \vert = \vert  (A e_j)_i\vert \leq \vert A e_j \vert \leq \Lambda \vert e_j \vert =\Lambda, \end{align*} so $$\vert D^\alpha g(x) \vert \leq  \Lambda^k \sup_{\vert \beta\vert = k} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n}\vert D^\beta f(x)\vert \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k=1}^n 1= C \Lambda^k \sup_{\vert \beta\vert = k} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n}\vert D^\beta f(x)\vert  $$ with $C>0$ depending only on $n$ and $k$.

Comment: It looks OK to me, thanks for your nice answer!